# ObjectDataSource Select Question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, objectdatasource

Is it possible to get to the object that an ObjectDataSource creates when calling the select function? Not the result of the select function itself but the object that is creates from the parameter specified in `TypeName`.

I would like to call some other functions on that same instance after `Select` is called. 
The other solution would be to DataBind manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ObjectCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.objectcreated.aspx) event will be able to give you the instance you want...

You'll have to hold a reference to that until you handle the [Selected event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selected.aspx)

Comment: Sometimes it's so simple you don't think it's possible.

Comment: Not often enough that you come to expect it ;)